# How to pause running thread and restart same thread when needed?

Tags: java, thread-safety

i want to pause thread which is writing messages in file by iterate message list. When message list is empty i want thread to stop and thread is resumed when message in a list.

I know stop,suspend (),resume methods is deprecated but if thread is continuously in background it consumes cpu. I did lots of googling but can't find proper answer. please any one help me out

Here is my code:

```java
 private Thread mFileWriterThread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public synchronized void run()         {
        while (mIsRunning) {
            synchronized (mMessageList) {
                Iterator it = mMessageList.iterator();
                while ((it.hasNext())) {
                    String message = (String) it.next();
                    writeToFile(fileOutputStream, message);
                    mMessageList.remove(message);

                }
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) exists for. It has a [take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) method that forces a thread to block until an Object is avalaible. Your problem can be solved with a simple producer-consumer design.

I'm pasting here a minimal snippet taken from the Oracle examples:

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   Object produce() { ... }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   void consume(Object x) { ... }
 }
```

Of course Consumer an Producer have to share the queue somehow (just passing it to the constructor as shown in the example will work fine).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use wait() to make the thread block*. And then call notify() to wake up the thread again. Google for "java wait notify" will give you a tutorial.

*Block here mean wait without using any resources, until an other thread wake it up.